# Composing a 16th note run

Tags: piano, musical-forms

I have troubles composing my first Impromptu, which is in the key of Eb Major. I'm composing it in the form of A-B-A. With the A section being "Andante cantabile". I want the B section to be "Allegro Con Fuoco" with a 16th note run. But i have troubles with composing a 16th note run, is there a specific way to it? Any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to run before you can walk? What actual problems are there that cause trouble? A 16th note run doesn't need to be 16 notes long! It could be just a short run of half a dozen notes, used as a motif.

Comment: First write the notes that you want to hear. Then learn how to play them.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no one way to do it, but consider the high notes of the run as a melody (which need not coincide with the beats), with the other notes as arpeggiated notes from the harmony, using non-harmonic tones as needed. You can then work backwards by blocking in a simple melody and breaking it up into filigree work afterwards.

Comment: I still don't understand, if you may explain a little more.

Comment: When you are writing fast runs, they still have elements of melody to them, whether you write them as scale runs or arpeggio runs. The high notes and, to a lesser extent, low notes of the runs are important. The notes on the beats can be quite important as well. Your harmony is probably not going to move as fast as your run, so the notes in the run are going to relate to the underlying harmony as notes of the harmony or, occasionally (especially with scale runs) non-harmonic notes (passing notes and the like). You are going to need to give your runs structure, and, (_more_)

Comment: ...by paying attention to how the important notes in the runs relate to each other, you can make runs that are more than purely decorative. You can consider the high notes and low notes as horizontal layers that connect as melodies. Have a look, for instance at the first prelude of Bach's Well-tempered Clavier Book 1. There is logic to how Bach builds his figurations, both vertically in the harmonies used, and horizontally in his implied melodies.

Comment: Edited the comment - I forgot for a second that Bach fit each figuration (in 16ths) and its repeat into one bar.